# How did Hook find Gold in Season 2 and Emma in Season 3?

Tags: once-upon-a-time

In Season 2 of *Once Upon a Time*, Hook leaves Storybrooke using his ship in order to find Gold and take revenge on him.  He finds Gold in Neal's apartment building in New York City, and stabs him with his hook coated with the poison Dreamshade.  And in Season 3, Hook uses a magic bean to go from the Enchanted Forest to the real world, in order to tell Emma that her family needs her help to fight the Wicked Witch.  He finds Emma in her apartment in New York City and tries to persuade her to come back to Storybrooke with him.

My question is, how did Hook find Gold in Season 2, and how did he find Emma in Season 3?

I remember that during Season 2, the creators said that the first question would be answered in future, but was it ever answered, either in the show or by the creators? What about the second question?